# php unexpected 'meta_value' (T_STRING)

Tags: php

im getting this error but cannot figure out why

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
echo itg_fetch_image('.$info['meta_value'].'); //the line giving error
Print "<tr>"; 
Print "<th>ID:</th> <td>".$info['meta_id'] . "</td> "; 
Print "<th>VALUE:</th> <td>".$info['meta_value']. "</td> "; 
Print "<th>DONE:</th> <td>YES</td> "; 
}
```

if i comment out this line it shows fine in the value td, ive tried everthing. taking the dots out the taking the comments out then adding "". itg_fetch_image is http://www.intechgrity.com/automatically-copy-images-png-jpeg-gif-from-remote-server-http-to-your-local-server-using-php/#

the code is ment to be echo itg_fetch_image('url') and all meta_values return a url string

Comment: `echo itg_fetch_image($info['meta_value']);`. The quotes are unecessary.

Comment: that worked, as you said it first post it as an answer and i will accept. thanks

Comment: I can't since the question is closed. Feel free to choose the first right answer as they deserve credit, too.

Answer (score 2):

The quotes on the echo line are causing the problem.
It should look like this:

```
echo itg_fetch_image($info['meta_value']);
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that `itg_fetch_image()` is  a function

try this:

```
echo itg_fetch_image($info['meta_value']);
```

you can just pass variable . do not need to use quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You must write it as

```
echo itg_fetch_image($info['meta_value']);
```